# ' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter

Tags: spring-form

This works no errors

```
<input name="amountOf[${status.index}]" size="2"/>
```

does not works The same getter and setter works on

```
<form:errors path="amountOf[${status.index}]" cssStyle="color: #ff0000;"/>
```

is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter

Have form a problem

Comment: It's really not clear what your problem is, mostly because you seem to be missing the relevant programming language tag. Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: this works private List<OrderItem> orderItemList;

 public List<OrderItem> getOrderItemList() {
  return orderItemList;
 }

 public void setOrderItemList(List<OrderItem> orderItemList) {
  this.orderItemList = orderItemList;
 }

Comment: this works with <input private List<OrderItem> orderItemList;

 public List<OrderItem> getOrderItemList() {
  return orderItemList;
 }

 public void setOrderItemList(List<OrderItem> orderItemList) {
  this.orderItemList = orderItemList;
 } form:error dosent works withprivate List<OrderItem> orderItemList;

 public List<OrderItem> getOrderItemList() {
  return orderItemList;
 }

 public void setOrderItemList(List<OrderItem> orderItemList) {
  this.orderItemList = orderItemList;
 }

Comment: Please [edit] your question - do not post as comments because code is unreadable like this.